# How to change balloon (tooltip) location in AmXYChart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I am using AmXYChart and I want to customize the location of the balloon which appears when I place my cursor over a bullet (point). The idea is on the picture below.
[image]

So I just want it to appear in other place but not right over the bullet. Does AmXYChart allow me to do that?

**Update 1:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#chartdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
</style>
<script src="amstock.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var chartData = [ {
            x : 10,
            y : 14
        }, {
            x : 5,
            y : 4
        }, {
            x : 11,
            y : 11
        }, {
            x : 10,
            y : 10
        }, {
            x : 15,
            y : 19
        }, {
            x : 13,
            y : 13
        }, {
            x : 1,
            y : 5
        } ];

        var chart = new AmCharts.AmXYChart();
        chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/";
        chart.dataProvider = chartData;
        chart.marginLeft = 35;
        chart.startDuration = 1.5;

        var xAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        xAxis.position = "left";
        xAxis.autoGridCount = true;
        chart.addValueAxis(xAxis);

        var yAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        yAxis.position = "bottom";
        yAxis.autoGridCount = true;
        chart.addValueAxis(yAxis);

        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.valueField = "value";
        graph.xField = "x";
        graph.yField = "y";
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.bullet = "round";
        graph.balloonText = "x:[[x]] y:[[y]]";
        chart.addGraph(graph);

        var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
        chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

        var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
        chartScrollbar.hideResizeGrips = false;
        chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

        var balloon = chart.balloon;
        balloon.adjustBorderColor = true;
        balloon.color = "#000000";
        balloon.fillColor = "#FFFFFF";
        balloon.cornerRadius = 3;

        balloon.borderThickness = 3;
        balloon.horizontalPadding = 17;
        balloon.offsetX = 50;
        balloon.offsetY = 8;

        chart.write("chartdiv");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 2:**
Funny thing I've noticed. When I include only the next AmChart js files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
```

offsetX and offsetY work fine, but I use stock charts on my page as well as xycharts. And when I try to include amstock.js after these two files, like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<script src="amstock.js"></script> // amstock.js located in the same folder where my HTML file is located, so it is ok.
```

offsetX and offsetY don't work - balloon appears with default offsets (right over the bullet). So it seems that those files don't get along with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes am chart provides option for balloon location

```
"balloon": {
    "borderThickness": 3,
    "horizontalPadding": 17,
    "offsetX": 50,
    "offsetY": 8
}
```

offsetX , and offsetY are horizontal and vertical distance from mouse pointer

Comment: I saw these offsetX and offsetY fields in AmCharts documentation. I tried them and I can assure you they didn't work for me at all. Do you have any ideas why it could happen? 
I will update my question with my javascript code soon

Comment: @AntonKasyanchuk just make jsfiddle for this one so i can look over

Comment: I didn't understand how to add amstock.js in jsfiddle because I was using it first time so I've added all the code except <script src="amstock.js"></script>. Now it seems to be not working but you can see it by this link http://jsfiddle.net/r92Us/

Comment: Can't the issue be in the way I have access to offsetX and offsetY ?

Comment: You should include amcharts.js and xy.js, not stock.js file: http://jsfiddle.net/qGe47/

Comment: But how come I could do everything I want (except the balloon offsets) with single stock.js file included? I also already use some stock charts in my web site, will amcharts.js and stock.js get along with each other within one page?

Comment: look this jsfiidle for how to include JS file of amcharts http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: @AntonKasyanchuk sorry!!! http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/# click on edit you can check fiddle for this chart

Comment: @ddw147 Thank you, after creating jsfiddle I was able to understand why the offsets hadn't been working for me. The reason was in amstock.js file I used before, there's something wrong with it. after I replaced it with the one from http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js my AmXYChart became working  fine (I mean offsetX and offsetY worked ok). But as I replaced my old amstock.js file with http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js my stock chart stopped working. I got an error when trying to sort the panels, like: chart.panels.sort - I get error "Cannot read property 'construct' of undefined"

Comment: Can this be a version issue?

Comment: Well the offsets issue is clear to me, but unfortunately this new problem with stock charts still need a solution.

Comment: All the issues was caused by using AmCharts version 2 but not 3

Answer (score 0):

I could not get these offsets to work and filed a ticket with amcharts. Great support. They came back telling me that there is one additional (fixedPosition) parameter that needs to be set.

They promised to update their docs.

Here is what worked for me:

```
"balloon": {
    "borderThickness": 3,
    "horizontalPadding": 17,
    "fixedPosition": false,
    "offsetX": 50,
    "offsetY": 8
}
```